# What permission should be enabled to create user?

Tags: sql-server

What permission do i need to enable to a user to be able to create other user's ,role's .
I tried giving him the role db_securityadmin still didn't work.

Comment: ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372834/permissions-required-for-create-user-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requires ALTER ANY LOGIN or ALTER LOGIN permission on the server and ALTER ANY USER permission on the database.

Comment: could you send me the query to do this if you don't mind i'm trying to write the query but it won't work .

And how would i do it for a specific database if you could tell me too.

Comment: you can use  `USE DATABASE_NAME;  
GRANT ALTER ANY USER TO USERNAME; 
GO`